# How thick does a spider web have to be to stop a 747 in flight?

Tags: aircraft

There is an idea I've heard since I was a kid that involves the relative strength of spider web. The claim is that if it were something like an inch thick it could stop an airplane in flight. How true is this? What thickness would be able to stop a 747?

Comment: Have you tried to look up the tensile strength of spider silk?

Comment: Might [skeptics.se] be better suited for verifying claims?

Comment: Honestly guys, lighten up. It's a fun question to talk and think about. If it's not for you let others enjoy it.

Comment: Not if you are scared of spiders...........

Comment: @AcidJazz Tuche

Answer (score 1):

It all depends on the conditions. The [mass of the plane, the velocity](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Boeing_747), [the silk strain, the breaking stress](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spider_silk) etc. play a role. By taking very large webs in order of 1km diameter you might end up with [such](http://ednieuw.home.xs4all.nl/Spiders/Info/SilkBoeing.html) results. Taking larger masses and webs in order of the wingspan would give you values of many meters thickness.

Comment: -1 This is a comment, not an answer.